# Utilizing addLiquid() and pourLiquid() methods to "transfer" liquids from object

Tags: inheritance, methods, constructor

i cannot think of a better name to describe my problem. However, i will provide some context to the question i am facing.

Essentially, i am struggling with adding all of the liquid from my Glass2 object to my Glass1 object using my pourLiquid() and addLiquid() methods . Here is the code:

*NOTE:
 - GLcap is Glass Capacity
 - GLliq is Glass Liquid
 - GLcol is Glass Color

```
package glass;
public class Glass
{
    private int GLcap;
    private int GLliq;
    private String GLcol;
    public int getGLcap()
{
    return GLcap;
}
public void setGLcap(int cap)
{
    GLcap = cap;
}
public int getGLliq()
{
    return GLliq;
}
public void setGLliq(int liq)
{
    GLliq = liq;
}
public String getGLcol()
{
    return GLcol;
}
public void setGLcol(String col)
{
    GLcol = col;
}


public Glass(int cap)
{
    GLcap = 0;
}

public Glass(int cap, int liq, String col)
{
    GLcap = cap;
    GLliq = liq;
    GLcol = col;  
}

public void addLiquid(int liq)
{
    GLliq = GLliq + liq;
}


public void pourLiquid(int liq)
{
    GLliq = GLliq - liq;
}
```

}

This is my inheritance:

```
package glass;
public class HW7 extends Glass{
     public HW7 (int cap, int liq, String col)
     {
         super(cap, liq, col);
     }
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    HW7 Glass1 = new HW7 (750, 0, "Transparent");
    HW7 Glass2 = new HW7 (1000, 900, "Pink");

}
```

}

If the question is still vague, please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Separate the concerns and identify the *actors*; you should create a Pourer class - the thing/person responsible for transferring liquid from one glass to another.

Something like this:

```
class Pourer {
    public void pour(Glass from, Glass to, int liq) {
        from.pourLiquid(liq);
        to.addLiquid(liq);
    }
}
```

Then:

```
new Pourer().pour(glass1, glass2, amount);
```

Your pour/add liquid methods should throw exceptions if too much liquid is passed to them.

Comment: Thank you for answering!